# Possible Retina issue with OpenGL ES on iPhone?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, retina-display

This is probably linked to [another unsolved mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975089/why-isnt-this-orthographic-vertex-shader-producing-the-correct-answer) of mine.

I'm drawing Orthographic 2d on iPhone, using real device and simulator.  I'm trying to color my pixels a given color depending on how far they are from arbitrary point in pixelspace of 'A', which I pass in (hard code).  I'm doing everything in Retina 960x640 resolution.  I calculate distance from A to `gl_FragCoord`, and I color based on leaping between 2 colors with the 'max' being 300px distance.

When on simulator (with retina display) I need to give a center point of "460" pixels for screen midpoint X.. Y I give 160px, and I look for distance of '300'px.. to get **the same effect** on device I need center of 960X and distance of 150 to get the same results (interestingly, px 80 doesn't give the same results I want but 160 could be an overshoot on the original...)

Obviously a retina issue is at play.  But where, and how, and how do I find and fix it?

I'm using:

`glViewport(0, 0, 960.0f, 640.0f);`

and:

`glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);`
`glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &framebufferHeight);`

And:

`[self setView:[[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]];`
`[(EAGLView *)[self view] setContentScaleFactor:2.0f];`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't hardcode "glViewport(0, 0, 960.0f, 640.0f);", setup the viewport this way:

```
glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);
```

Also don't hardcode the content scale, you can findout the content scale with:

```
float contentScale = 1.0f;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)]) {
    contentScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
```

About the pixel distance, since you want the distance to be the double with retina display, you can add an uniform to your shader with the content scale.

Comment: I've since replaced those with the correct generic values - however I was hardcoding to be very clear that the problem wasn't there.  Carefully look at the Q - retina display on my iPhone 4 device and "retina" iPhone device on simulator behave differently

Answer (score 0):

Now iOS devices can have multiple different screens, and a `UIWindow` can be placed in a non-main screen. In that case, you can use `self.view.window.screen.scale` to get current screen's scale dynamically.